# How to delete a lot of messages through Discord's API using Python?

Tags: python, api, discord.py

I am making a Python bot for my Discord server, but I don't know how to do a massive deletion of user and bot messages... Please help me!

Here's my code:

````
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def wipe(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == '[Командир]', ctx.message.guild.roles)
    if role in ctx.message.author.roles:
        await ctx.message.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'```css\n[ERROR] >>> У вас нет права это сделать!```')
````

This code can delete only 1 message.

I am using discord.py version 1.2.5.

Comment: Exactly which messages do you want to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a bulk delete using the [`TextChannel.delete_messages`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.delete_messages) method.
Alternatively, you can use the [`TextChannel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge) convenience method.

Answer (score 0):

Not super versed in the API but a basic way to delete all of a certain user's messages could just be

```
if role in ctx.message.author.roles:
     for msg in ctx.message.author.messages:        
          await msg.delete()
```

Comment: [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) does not have a `messages` attribute. Additionally, a bulk delete should be used instead of looping through and spamming the API with multiple single message deletion requests.